# Hide the menu area for certain components

Tags: menu, joomla, components, hide

I'm designing a joomla component and I wants to hide all the items from the side menu only for a specific component page.
Is it possible in Joomla? if yes How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for a component in the URL in your index.php:

```
<?php
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
if (!$option == "com_yourcomponent") {
?>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" style="xhtml" />
<?php    
}
?>
```

You can also check other params such as

```
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
$task = JRequest::getCmd('task');
```